Find speed with which a steel bar sinks through ice (Reif)
Problem 8.8 of Reif's book deals with ice regelation and asks to find the speed at which a steel bar of dimensions $a \times b \times c$ ($a$ is the height) sinks through a block of ice maintained at temperature $T_0=0^\circ$C. The answer needs to be in terms of the latent heat of fusion $l$ per gram of ice, the densities of the ice and water, the thermal conductivity of steel, the temperature of the ice, the acceleration due to gravity, the mass of the bar and the dimensions $a,b,c$. It assumes the latent heat of the phase transition is exchanged mainly with the bar.
My problem is that I don't understand how the temperature difference between the top and bottom of the bar can be determined without additional information, for example their heat capacities. Let $T_t,T_b$ be the temperatures of the top and bottom of the bar and $p_0 =1 \textrm{atm},p_b$ be the corresponding pressures.  An online solution I found, which seems to be what Reif is aiming for, claims that the difference is given by the Clausius-Clapeyron relation:
$$\frac {\Delta p} {\Delta T}\approx \frac {dp} {dt}=\frac l {T(v_{ice}-v_{water})},$$
which  seems to suggest that the temperature of the top of the bar is $T_t=T_0$ and of the bottom is $T_b=T(p_b)$, the temperature on the phase equilibrium curve corresponding to the pressure $p_b$. I don't understand why this would be the case. The system is in a steady state but not in equilibrium, so we can't just equate the bar's temperature to the ice. Even if we could, why would the ice below have temperature $T(p_b)$ and not $T_0$ or any temperature between (and similarly for the ice above)? After all, the temperature is usually assumed constant during a phase transition, and the ice certainly begins at temperature $T_0$, it just experiences a change in pressure.
I tried adding the assumptions that pressure equilibrium is reached much faster than thermal equilibrium, and that the ice flows above the bar as soon as it melts. In this case the phase transition could be divided into an adiabatic change in pressure followed by an isobaric change in temperature. This makes things a bit better: as long as $T_b\geq T(p_b)$ and $T_t\leq T_0$, the bottom ice flows up when it has pressure $p_b$ and temperature $T(p_b)$, while the top ice freezes when it has pressure $p_0$ and temperature $T_0$, but this still doesn't explain why the bar would have these temperatures. The bottom part, for example, constantly alternates between contact with melted ice at temperature $T(p_b)$ and new solid ice at temperature $T_0$, while heat flows into it from above, so the temperature can have all kinds of values...

I don't think this question should be closed. It clearly shows some effort and thought has been put to it.

@agaminon effort and thought are not sufficient to determine if a question should be closed or not; although, it at least tends to be a necessary one. I would give other justification for reopening. One could put a lot of thought and effort into a PSE post and it still not be suitable for the site.

Hint: (only a  hint because it is a homework problem but you have got through the half of it, so...) to the CC equation (there is a typo in your question) you need to add the heat conductivity through the steel bar of thickness $a$, say, $\dot q = -\kappa bc \frac{\Delta T}{a}$ and equate this with $\ell \rho_i bc s$, where $s=\frac{dx}{dt}$ is the rate of sinking with $\rho_i bcs$ is the mass of the ice melted per unit time.

Important background: In the Clausius–Clapeyron equation, $\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta T}$ refers to the slope of the equilibrium phase-change coexistence curve, not necessarily to any actual pressure and temperature shifts at any time in any given problem. (I think you reason this out in your last paragraph.) For this reason, I recommend typographically distinguishing it as, say, $\frac{\Delta P^\star}{\Delta T^\star}$ or $\left.\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta T}\right|_\mathrm{solid–liquid}$ to reduce ambiguity. Again, $\Delta P^\star$ and $\Delta T^\star$ refer to coupled shifts in phase-change conditions, not necessarily in system conditions.
Reif's problem 8.8 is as follows:
A steel bar of rectangular cross section (height a and width b) is placed on a
block of ice with its ends extending a trifle as shown in the figure. A weight of
mass m is hung from each end of the bar. The entire system is at 0°C. As a
result of the pressure exerted by the bar, the ice melts beneath the bar and
refreezes above the bar. Heat is therefore liberated above the bar, conducted
through the metal, and then absorbed by the ice beneath the bar. (We assume
that this is the most important way in which heat reaches the ice immediately
beneath the bar in order to melt it.) Find an approximate expression for the
speed with which the bar thus sinks through the ice. The answer should be in
terms of the latent heat of fusion I per gram of ice, the densities ρi and ρw of
ice and water respectively, the thermal conductivity k of steel, the temperature
T (0°C) of the ice, the acceleration due to gravity g, the mass m, and the
dimensions a, b, and c, where c is the width of the block of ice.
When the weight of the newly added bar augments the atmospheric pressure by $\Delta P^\star=\Delta P$—an actual change—it's the equilibrium ice melting temperature that decreases according to $\Delta T^\star = \frac{\Delta P^\star\Delta v T}{L}= \frac{\Delta P\Delta v T}{L}$, and this shift can be minimal relative to $T_0$. (Indeed, the problem is written to assume that it's minimal.) Additionally, temperatures must be continuous across interfaces. Since the ice in contact with the bottom of the bar is now above its melting temperature, it melts, absorbing latent heat $L$. This endothermic process cools the interface and surrounding region, as mediated by the material and geometrical properties of the setup, some of which are unspecified, as you note.
The newly obtained liquid water, as a fluid, is squeezed out of the way of the heavier steel above. When the interface has cooled to $T_0-|\Delta T^*|$, rapid melting stops. A temperature gradient through the steel (stated to be the predominant heat transfer mechanism) is coupled by Fourier's law to heat flow, which is supplied by the exothermic freezing of readily available liquid water into ice at the top of the bar. (Why does it freeze? Because the bar below is tending to cool below 0°C.) Reif's figure illustrates this new stage of slow, steady downward movement:

The phase changes occur close to equilibrium. (I review the extremely rapid kinetics of phase changes here.) The fluid movement is faster still. If the ice directly below the bottom of the bar were any colder than $T_0-|\Delta T^*|$, it wouldn't melt; if it were any hotter, it would melt nearly immediately. Similarly, if the liquid water at the top—at atmospheric pressure—were any colder than $T_0$, it would freeze nearly immediately. This fixes the actual temperature drop $\Delta T=\Delta T^\star$ vertically through the bar for the purposes of solving this problem. It's because the movement is so slow that the Clausius–Clapeyron slope—an equilibrium relation—can be used to approximate the actual system behavior.
What about ice near the bottom of the bar? Its pressure $P^\prime$ is lower than $P_0+\Delta P$ because ice, being a solid, dissipates localized stress fields with increasing distance. Its temperature must be lower than the corresponding Clausius–Clapeyron $\Delta T^{\prime\star}$ shift for that particular pressure shift $\Delta P^{\prime\star}=P^\prime-P_0$, or it would melt. (And of course, its temperature must also be above $T_0-|\Delta T|$ because it's always been surrounded by the same phase at temperatures higher than that.) So I don't agree with the question's statement that "The bottom part, for example, constantly alternates between contact with melted ice at temperature $T(p_b)$ and new solid ice at temperature $T_0$." A more nuanced look at the spatial temperature variation is necessary than idealizing it as discrete jumps. And remember that the problem states that no part of the ice or steel strays notably from 0°C.
What about liquid water moving around the bar to the top? It ultimately warms from $T_0-\Delta T$ to $T_0$ before freezing. Could it freeze along the way? Conceivably, but the problem states that it freezes at the top of the bar.
Is (sensible) heat transfer occurring throughout the ice and water? Yes. But Reif instructs us specifically that that this heat transfer isn't kinetically limiting the sinking of the bar—that it's conduction through the bar that dominates the kinetics. This is why the specific heat capacity of the water, for example, doesn't appear in the final relation.
In summary, I think you're right to examine the question and assumptions as carefully as you have. There's one "obvious" way to combine all the given variables (and no others) into a speed, but that doesn't mean it's appropriate to skim the problem statement and just write down a dimensionally correct answer (and you didn't). There are many reasonable questions that could be raised as to what's going on in all regions and interfaces here, and hopefully you can now appreciate how carefully the problem was constructed to send the reader in the direction of the intended analysis.
Does this resolve the issue(s)?

If I understand correctly, I was right that there was an implicit assumption about characteristic times, just not the one I was thinking of. The assumption is 'the rate at which phase transition occurs for ice/water "beyond" the phase equilibrium line is much faster than the rate at which the bar can redistribute heat'. In this case a steady state is only possible when the temperatures of the bar's ends are the "phase equilibrium temperatures", since only then will it be cooled/heated slowly enough by the ice/water for the internal heat flow to keep up. Is that correct?

Agreed. -filling minimum comment length-
